# Water and air temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

Does the theory hold that if I blow warm air into a pool through tubing on the bottom it will raise the temperature of the water?

Comment: "the theory"--which one? It's an experimental result, too!

Comment: The question is not well posed.  You say "warm" air but is the pool colder or hotter? Why is tubing important? And what is your hypothesis about what would happen?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the temp of the air is greater than that of the water, then heat transfer will occur.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it doesn't have to be at the bottom!  As long as the 2 mediums (air and water) are of different temperatures, a heat transfer will definitely occur.